# Table with inconsistent starttime and stoptime

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, datediff

I have a table that contains a date, a starttime, and a stoptime.  I have several problems that I don't know how to solve for. Each row contains either a starttime OR a stoptime (not both).  While this itself is not a problem, I need to calculate the runtime by date.  Also, there are instances of multiple starttimes before there is a stoptime registered.  Assume the following:

```
Date, Starttime, Stoptime
4/1/2016, 23:00:00, NULL 
4/2/2016, NULL, 03:00:00
4/2/2016, 05:00:00, NULL
4/2/2016, 07:00:00, NULL
4/2/2016, NULL, 08:00:00
4/2/2016, 10:00:00, NULL
4/2/2016, NULL, 10:15:00
```

I need the output to be:

```
4/1/2016, 01:00:00
4/2/2016, 06:15:00
```

I have tried a few things, with very poor results.  Can any experts out there solve this problem?

Comment: What does the null values stands for? How do you get `6:15:00` ?

Comment: How do you want to calculate the runtime by date? Is it to find the latest Starttime for a given date (for example  `4/2/2016, 07:00:00, NULL`) and calculate the runtime by substracting the earliest stoptime `4/2/2016, NULL, 08:00:00`?
Could you add columns to the desired output?
Could you add how your output `4/1/2016, 01:00:00` and `4/2/2016, 06:15:00` was calculated?

Comment: You need to state the those exception case like multiple start before stop etc, how do you want to handle it. We can't decide for you

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way how you could handle this:

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([Date] date, [Starttime] time, [Stoptime] time)
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([Date], [Starttime], [Stoptime])
VALUES
    ('2016-04-01', '23:00:00', NULL),
    ('2016-04-02', NULL, '00:00:00'),
    ('2016-04-02', '00:00:00', NULL),
    ('2016-04-02', NULL, '03:00:00'),
    ('2016-04-02', '05:00:00', NULL),
    ('2016-04-02', '07:00:00', NULL),
    ('2016-04-02', NULL, '08:00:00'),
    ('2016-04-02', '10:00:00', NULL),
    ('2016-04-02', NULL, '10:15:00')
;
```

SQL:

```
select 
  convert(date, StartTime), 
  convert(time, dateadd(second, sum(datediff(second, StartTime, EndTime)),0)) 
from (
  select
    min(Time) as StartTime,
    min(case when Type = 0 then Time end) as EndTime
  from
  (
    select
      sum(Type) over (order by Time asc, Type Asc) as GRP, *
    from ( 
      select
        isnull(lag(Type) over (order by Time asc, Type Asc), -1) as LagType, *
      from (
        select
          case when Starttime is NULL then 0 else 1 end as Type,
          case when Starttime is NULL 
            then convert(datetime, [Date]) + convert(datetime, Stoptime)
            else convert(datetime, [Date]) + convert(datetime, Starttime) end as Time
        from
          #Table1
      ) A
    ) B
    where Type != 1 or LagType != 1 
  ) C
  group by GRP
) D
group by convert(date, StartTime)
```

Result:

```
2016-04-01     01:00:00
2016-04-02     06:15:00
```

This requires that you have start and stop record in your data for each of the days, so you'll need to use union or something like that to add that to your initial data.

The innermost select generates typing (0/1) for the rows and calculates the date + start / end time into a single column. The next one adds TypeLag to the data and it's used to remove the duplicate start records. The next select has a running total over Type, so that start and end records belonging together will have a unique group number. The rest will just pick the start time + earliest end time from each group and calculate the durations.